# How to calculate the neighbors of a list of Delaunay triangles know the vertex of each triangle in Python

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay

I have been working on this for quite some time. I have a list of Delaunay triangles with knowing all the vertex, now I need to calculate the neighbors of each triangle.

I know that python has the module Delaunay in scipy.spatial, which can be used to calculate the simplices and the neighbors knowing a list of points. But how can i calculate the neighbors given all the simplices.

The list of triangles look like this:

```
[[[634706.612442, 3086432.2967], [635268.645733, 3086636.61233],[634830.249107, 3087157.20293]]
[[634706.612442, 3086432.2967], [634830.249107, 3087157.20293], [634401.962216, 3086874.97886]]
[[656237.10083, 3061518.637755], [656776.863279, 3061883.38021], [656330.134218, 3062431.49804]]
[[656237.10083, 3061518.637755], [656330.134218, 3062431.49804], [655787.935768, 3061995.043438]]
[[656541.118122, 3060981.747767], [657223.592341, 3061335.26239], [656776.863279, 3061883.38021]]
[[656541.118122, 3060981.747767], [656776.863279, 3061883.38021], [656237.10083, 3061518.637755]]]
```

The x,y coordinate of each vertex are given.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking that is not in the spatial library. If you have the simplices then you have the vertices no?

Comment: Yes, I have the vertices, then I am looking for the neighbors of each triangle.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all edges of the triangles and test if it shared the same edges.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! That's a good option. But I have too many of these triangles, more than 40,000. These triangles are the result of grid generator. It will be quite time consuming in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Actually, there is such module in Python that the neighbors of every triangle can be obtained with knowing the vertices of each triangle.

Such function is **matplotlib.tri.Triangulation(x, y, triangles=None, mask=None)** 
This class has two attributes: **edges** and **neighbors** that can be used to calculate the neighbors of each triangle.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: Look at all the combinations of the simplices and then build a graph in a dictionary list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1.1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
tri = Delaunay(points)

# Visualize Delaunay Graph
plt.triplot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], tri.simplices)
plt.plot(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], 'o')
for j, p in enumerate(points):
    plt.text(p[0] - 0.03, p[1] + 0.03, j, ha='right')  # label the points

graph = defaultdict(list)
for simplex in tri.simplices:
    sc = permutations(simplex, 2)
    for cc in sc:
        if cc[1] not in graph[cc[0]]:
            graph[cc[0]].append(cc[1])

print(graph)
```